# pl/sql Return Interval Calculations in Function

Tags: function, plsql

I have some tables that track bus lines, stops, and the schedule they are on. I'm attempting to create a function that returns the travel time between two bus stops on the same line but I just can't get the function to work as expected.

Code for function:

```
create or replace function total_time_func(sch_id in sched.shid%type, stop_start in stops.sname%type, stop_end in stops.sname%type)
     return interval day to second is
     t_time interval day to second;
     start_time stop_sched.scheduled_arrival%type;
     end_time stop_sched.scheduled_arrival%type;

begin

     select scheduled_arrival 
     into start_time
     from stop_sched, stops
     where stop_sched.sid = stops.sid
     and stop_sched.shid = sch_id
     and stops.sname = stop_start;

     select scheduled_arrival
     into end_time
     from stop_sched, stops
     where stop_sched.sid = stops.sid
     and stop_sched.shid = sch_id
     and stops.sname = stop_end;

     t_time := end_time - start_time;

     return t_time;

end;
```

The function compiles without returning an error; however, as soon as I run the program to call the returned value from the function, I receive an error.

Program to call the returned value from function:

```
declare
     total_time interval day to second;

begin 
     total_time := total_time_func(1, '5th', '7th');

     if total_time > 0 
         then dbms_output.put_line('The total time is: ' || total_time);
    else dbms_output.put_line('Stops Not Found');
    end if;
end;
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 16
ORA-06512: at line 5
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly and I've rewritten and started from scratch multiple times without success. It's also notable that I understand I could likely accomplish this without using a function; however, I'm new to working with functions and I want the practice of writing them rather than just giving up.

These are my tables for reference:

```
create table lines 
(lid int, 
lname varchar(30),  
num_station int, 
status int,
primary key(lid));

create table stops
(sid int, 
sname varchar(30), 
address varchar(100), 
status int, 
primary key(sid));

create table stop_line
(lid int, 
sid int,  
seq int, 
primary key(lid,sid),
foreign key(lid) references lines,
foreign key(sid) references stops);

create table sched
(shid int,  
lid int,  
direction int,   
primary key (shid), 
foreign key (lid) references lines);

create table stop_sched 
(shid int, 
sid int, 
scheduled_arrival interval day to second, 
primary key (shid, sid),
foreign key(shid) references sched, 
foreign key(sid) references stops);
```

As a side note, I initially also included the following statements in the function body; however, I wasn't able to compile the function at all without returning an error:

```
select shid 
into sch_id
from sched
where sch_id = shid;

select sname
into stop_start
from stops
where stop_start = sname;

select sname
into stop_end
from stops
where stop_end = sname;
```

The error it returns when these statements are added:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
9/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/10     PLS-00403: expression 'SCH_ID' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH 
statement
11/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
14/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/10     PLS-00403: expression 'STOP_START' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a 
SELECT/FETCH statement
16/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
19/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
20/10     PLS-00403: expression 'STOP_END' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a 
SELECT/FETCH statement
21/5      PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
Errors: check compiler log
```

Any guidance you might be able to provide is hugely appreciated, as I'm having quite a bit of trouble working with functions. Thanks!

Edited to include sample table values. The first and last rows of the stop_sched table should satisfy the parameters (sch_id = 1, stop_start = '5th', stop_end = '7th'), but the function returns no data found.

```
insert into stops values(1,'5th', '42 5th Avenue, Buffalo, NY 14201,1);
insert into stops values(2,'10th', ‘889 10th Avenue, Buffalo, NY 14201',1);
insert into stops values(3,'Main', '10 Main Street, Buffalo, NY 14201',1);
insert into stops values(4,'7th', '900 7th Avenue, Buffalo, NY 14201',0);

insert into schedule values(1,1, 1);
insert into schedule values(2,1, 1);

insert into stop_sched values(1, 1, interval '7:30:00.00' hour to second);
insert into stop_sched values(1, 2, interval '7:40:00.00' hour to second);
insert into stop_sched values(1, 3, interval '7:50:00.00' hour to second);
insert into stop_sched values(1, 4, interval '8:10:00.00' hour to second);
```

Comment: In a few days we will reach the year 2020, please learn the new join syntax. "No data found" means that no data was found in the table with the criteria in a where clause. Since we do not know you data, we cannot tell you what you are doing wrong. Just run the selects one by one and you will find the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
Error report -
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 16
ORA-06512: at line 5
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
*Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

This error clearly says that your query inside the function didnt `return` any rows and your anonymous block through execution.

The code is working as expected. See below demo:

Table Prep:

```
CREATE  TABLE stops (
    sid       INT,
    sname     VARCHAR(30),
    address   VARCHAR(100),
    status    INT
);

insert into stops values (1,'A','DFDFD',1);
insert into stops values (2,'B','FDKJH',3);
insert into stops values (3,'C','IOIOS',4);
insert into stops values (4,'D','LKJJA',5);


CREATE   TABLE stop_sched (
    sid                 INT,
    scheduled_arrival   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND
);

insert into stop_sched values (1,'3 12:30:06.7');
insert into stop_sched values (2,'4 12:30:06.7');
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_time_func
(
    -- sch_id       IN  number, --sched.shid%TYPE,
     stop_start   IN  varchar2,--stops.sname%TYPE,
     stop_end      IN  varchar2
) 
RETURN INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND IS
    t_time       INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    start_time   stop_sched.scheduled_arrival%TYPE;
    end_time     stop_sched.scheduled_arrival%TYPE;
BEGIN

     select scheduled_arrival 
     into start_time
     from stop_sched
     Inner join  stops
     ON stop_sched.sid = stops.sid
    -- and stop_sched.shid = sch_id
     and stops.sname = stop_start;

     select scheduled_arrival
     into end_time
     from stop_sched
     inner join stops
     ON stop_sched.sid = stops.sid
     --and stop_sched.shid = sch_id
     and stops.sname = stop_end;

    t_time   := end_time - start_time;    

    RETURN t_time;
END;
```

Execution:

```
select total_time_func('A','B') OUTPUT from dual;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /
     OUTPUT 
     -------
     +01 00:00:00.000000



 SQL> 
    DECLARE
        total_time   INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    BEGIN
        total_time   := total_time_func('A', 'B');
        IF
            total_time > 0
        THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('The total time is: ' || total_time);
        ELSE
            dbms_output.put_line('Stops Not Found');
        END IF;

    END;
```

Output:

```
Stops Not Found
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking this down. I guess my confusion is that I have specific rows  that *should* satisfy the criteria and be returned when entering those parameters, so it's unexpected for it to return "no data found."

I notice you omit the sch_id from the function. Is there a reason you omitted this and could it be causing an issue with matching the criteria in the function? 

I've also edited my question to include sample code. (There are additional schedules in the table but I only included sch_id 1 values since this is the sch_id in the parameters)

Comment: @Rash8151 ` you omit the sch_id` -- Yes coz i was just giving a demo. You need to work on the joins and check if the data exists bu putting all relevant joins with all tables in use.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue I had was in the program to call the function, not the function itself. I changed my IF clause to the below and it executed as expected.

```
IF
        total_time is not null
    THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('The total time is: ' || total_time);
    ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('Stops Not Found');
    END IF;
```

Using "total_time > 0" returned no data because it's a different datatype than the variable returned from the function.

I also added the following exception to the function.

```
exception
     when no_data_found
     then dbms_output.put_line('No Data Found');
     return NULL;
```